# Is this a valid proof that the boundary of a set on a metric space is closed?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

The definition that I have been given of the boundary of a subset $A$ of a metric space $X$ is:

$$\partial A=\{x\in X:\forall r\in \mathbb{R}, B_r(x)\cap A \neq\emptyset \text{ and } B_r(x)\cap A^c\neq\emptyset\}$$
So with this definition, we would have
$$(\partial A)^c=\{x\in X:\exists r\in \mathbb{R}, B_r(x)\cap A =\emptyset \text{ or } B_r(x)\cap A^c=\emptyset\}$$
$$(\partial A)^c=\{x\in X:\exists r\in \mathbb{R}, B_r(x)\cap A =\emptyset\}\cup\{x\in X:\exists r\in \mathbb{R}, B_r(x)\cap A^c=\emptyset\}$$
$$(\partial A)^c=\operatorname{int}A\cup \operatorname{int}A^c$$
Thus, the complement of the boundary of $A$ is the union of two open sets, in consequence, it is open. Then, $((\partial A)^c)^c=\partial A$ is closed.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for bringing it to my atention, corrected it.

Comment: This proof is correct and complete.

Comment: I changed $intA$ to $\operatorname{int}A,$ coded as \operatorname{int}A. Notice that in $\operatorname{int}(A),$ coded as \operatorname{int}(A), you see less blank space to the right of of "int" than you have in the form without the punctuation. That illustrates the context-dependent nature of the spacing when \operatorname{} is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that’s fine. You can also do it a little more directly: the definition of $\operatorname{bdry}A$ says that $x\in\operatorname{bdry}A$ iff $x\in\operatorname{cl}A\cap\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus A)$, i.e., that $\operatorname{bdry}A=\operatorname{cl}A\cap\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus A)$, and since this is the intersection of two closed sets, it is closed.

While your definition of the boundary is stated in terms of metric spaces, it’s just a special case of the definition for topological spaces in general, and the same argument shows that $\operatorname{bdry}A$ is closed in all topological spaces.